# RuntimeError on Kattis Problem "Job Expenses" but my local tests are OK

Tags: python, runtime-error

I'm new to programming and doing some problems on kattis. But on this one

https://open.kattis.com/problems/jobexpenses

All the given test are correct but when I upload this:

```
i =input()
k = input().split(" ")

summe=[]

for n in k:
    if int(n)<0:
        summe.append(int(n))
x=sum(summe)

print(abs(x))
```

I get a Runtime Error. I don't know what to do now. I'm happy for any tips that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make assumptions like how the input is spaced. Use `split()` instead of `split(" ")`.

Comment: Note for others since the OP seems to have abandoned their question: I had of course tested it, with this fix it works and gets accepted.

Comment: It's surprising that this is the case. Kattis usually tries to adhere to strict input formats. I believe almost all of their input should be strictly and precisely delimited by single spaces and newlines, so I'd venture that this might be a bug in the test input.